# does zookeeper.session.timeout.ms apply to consumer or broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

> zookeeper.session.timeout.ms: ZooKeeper session timeout. If the consumer fails to heartbeat to ZooKeeper for this period of time it is considered dead and a rebalance will occur.

From my understanding, this configuration is a broker setting. From a netstat command, it also shows that only kafka connects to zookeeper. The kafka consumer is not connecting to zookeeper at all. Can anyone explain what the *consumer* means in this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In old Kafka versions (until 0.8, later it was optional), consumer used ZooKeeper for storing offsets. Now, it uses internal Kafka topic for that and the consumer no longer communicates with ZooKeeper.

See also: https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/

Comment: Does it mean this settings in new version after 0.8 has no effect at all when internal Kafka topic is used for storing offsets?

Comment: Yes, for consumer there won't be any effect. If you check Kafka docs for older version: https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html then you can see that this setting is present for consumer config. In the latest Kafka version, this setting is present only for the broker.